# ASP.NET MVC No route in the route table matches the supplied values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm facing a strange issue, where the following line works on multiple environment, but on one of our servers, it throws a System.InvalidOperationException: No route in the route table matches the supplied values.

```
@{Html.RenderAction("Action", "Home", new { area = "Custom" });}
```

Any ideas what to look for?

Contents of RouteConfig.cs:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        new[] { "Backoffice.Controllers" }
    );
```

And the contents of the CustomAreaRegistration.cs:

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
    context.MapRoute(
        "Custom_default",
        "Custom/{controller}/{action}",
        new { action = "Index" }
    );
}
```

Comment: did you deploy RouteConfig.cs file to the server and what are the contents of it?

Answer (score 0):

> Any ideas what to look for?

You can install a [Route debugger](http://www.nuget.org/packages/routedebugger/) to debug your routes, and see which routes server assigns to a specific URLs.